# Conditionally binding with Ninject in WebApi

Tags: c#, ninject.web.mvc

I'm trying to bind an interface in a way that Ninject can determine which concrete class to use by the version of the controller and find the most recent version of the adapter.

The controller and adapter both implement this interface:

```
public interface IVersioned {
    Version Version {get;set;}
}
```

I'd like to bind all adapters of IMyAdapter so I can get the closest version of adapter for the controller.

```
public class MyController {
    public MyController(IMyAdapter Adapter) {
    }
}
```

I've setup the NinjectDependencyResolver.  I've tried to use the Bind().ToMethod(...) but I cannot get the controller that is trying to get the adapter.  Is it possible to figure out what controller is trying to get the adapter.  I can tell it's a IMyController but I cannot get the instance so I can get the version of the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that instead of getting an instance that if I get the type of the controller I can read a static field from the type (x.Request.ParentRequest.Service) using reflection.  Then when I find the proper adapter I can create an instance.

Edit: found a simpler solution by using an attribute.